# Unlocking the Nexus 9 bootloader

Tags: bootloader, nexus-9

I'm trying to flash the [Android M Developer Preview](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html) onto my Nexus 9 (volantis) following [the steps from Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#instructions).

However, when executing the unlock command, I get an error that permission is denied:

```
$ fastboot oem unlock
...
(bootloader) ability is 0
(bootloader) Permission denied for this command!
OKAY [  0.006s]
finished. total time: 0.006s
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 13):

The instructions don't make mention of the setting in the device's developer options.

Make sure to enable the "OEM unlocking" setting there:

[image: Locate the "OEM unlocking" setting in the developer options][image: Enable it]